# How to submit a form to an external page using C# ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to submit data from a form to an external web page, but after submitting it, a "Thank you for contacting us" page appears.

```
<form action="HTTPS://WWW.externalPage.com/encoding?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <label class="form-label" for="first_name">first_name: </label>
                <input class="form-control mb-3" id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" required size="20" type="text" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <label class="form-label" for="last_name">last_name: </label>
                <input class="form-control mb-3" id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" required size="20" type="text" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <label class="form-label" for="mobile">mobile: </label>
                <input class="form-control mb-3" id="mobile" maxlength="40" name="mobile" required size="20" type="text" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <label class="form-label" for="email">email: </label>
                <input class="form-control mb-3" id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" required size="20" type="text" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <label class="form-label" for="company">company: </label>
                <input class="form-control mb-3" id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" required size="20" type="text" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-12 buttonSubmit">
                <input class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="Gracias()">
            </div>
        </form>
```

With this I am sending the data to the controller, but it must go to another web page (ex: http://web.ReciveData.com/)

I tried to send the form to the web page like this

```
<form action="http://web.ReciveData.com/" method="POST" class="row">
```

Submit button with "`Thanks()`" function:

```
<input class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="Thanks()">
```

JavaScript:

```
function Thanks() {
    window.location.href("http://web.MyWebPage.com/Home/Thanks")
}
```

Also try this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var formulario = document.getElementById('form');
    var validateName = function (e) {
        if (formulario.first_name.value.length == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };

    var validateEmail = function () {
        if (formulario.email.value.length == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };

    var validatePhone = function () {
        if (formulario.mobile.value == "") {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };

    var validateMsj = function () {
        if (formulario.mensage.value.length == 0) {            
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };

    var validar = function () {
        return validateName() &&
            validateEmail() &&
            validatePhone() &&
            validateMsj();
    };
  formulario.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);
    async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (validar()) {

            const form = new FormData(this);
            const response = await fetch(this.action, {
                method: this.method,
                body: form,
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                }
            });
            if (response.ok) {
                this.reset();
                window.location.href = 'Http://web.MyWebPage.com/Home/Thanks'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But it does not work. Basically what I'm trying to do is load the data, send it to the external web page, and a web page that I created to thank the contact is displayed.

I can think of absolutely nothing, and what I found on the internet are mostly basic examples..

I changed the header to

```
headers: {
          /* 'Accept': 'application /x-www-urlencoded'*/
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:': 'https://www.externalPage.com'
         }
```

And now the problem is on line `fetch(this.action)`:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid name
> at HTMLFormElement.handleSubmit

Comment: You are explicitly setting the window location to the thanks page. What do you expect to happen here?

Comment: I'm expecting to send the form to the corresponding web page, and show to the user the "Thanks, we will contact you" view

Comment: The browser will try to load the page at the location referenced in the form action attribute but the onclick handler you have is forcing the browser to load a different page before the form is submitted.

Comment: So, what should I do? I never did this before and the Demos are forms that points to an ActionResult in the controller, I never did and can´t understand how to point to an external webpage but show to the user a "Thanks" web page (internal view)

Comment: Your last code block, where you are posting the form content asynchronously and then redirecting, sounds like the right approach for what you are trying to do. Be aware that the default behavior of the form submit (as show in your first code block) is encoded as "application/x-www-urlencoded" while (I believe) the fetch method is going to encode the form content as a JSON block. Make sure your controller is expecting the difference. Work through getting the form post (fetch) to function correctly before you add the redirect code into your event listener.